# Explicitly scope a variable inside a function

Tags: javascript, function, scope, anonymous-function

I'm reading [this](http://helephant.com/2008/08/23/javascript-anonymous-functions/) article
and there is a paragraph:

> If you ever find yourself needing to **explicitly scope a variable**
>   inside a function you can use an anonymous function to do this. You
>   can actually create an anonymous function and then execute it straight
>   away and all the variables inside will be scoped to the anonymous
>   function:

```
 (function() {
        var myProperty = "hello world";
        alert(myProperty);
  })();
 alert(typeof(myProperty)); // undefined
```

I met with this already but still need some clarification why should I need to explicitly scope a variable inside a function when variables are implicitly scoped inside a function in Javascript.

Could you explain the purpose of this?

thank you

Comment: maybe because you don't want to overwrite the value of a global variable?

Comment: @Achshar Yes, but I couldn't imagine this situation. Raynos example opened my eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(function() { console.log(i) }, 10);
}

// alerts 10, 10 times

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    // explicitly scope i
    setTimout(function() { console.log(i) }, 10);
  })(i);
}
```

When generating functions inside other functions and accessing variables up the scope chain through closure scope it may be useful to "explicitly scope" a variable inside the outer function.

Although this is an anti pattern. The correct solution would be

```
var generateLogger = function(i) {
  return function() { console.log(i); };
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  setTimeout(generateLogger(i), 10);
}
```

Since generating functions in a loop is inefficient and bad practice.

There are no real use cases of "explicitly scoping" variables that can't be avoided by not creating functions inside other functions.

Comment: Thank you for answering the OP's question and providing an actual example

Comment: @Raynos : Thank you, now it's clear. There is only one strange thing. The output in the first example is (54, 10, ... 10) and (undefined, 0, ..., 9). Why there is one more extra value? and why in the first case it isn't (54, 0, ..., 0), the last value of `i` overwrites the preceding values?

Comment: @xralf the `54` and `undefined` are the value of executing the "expression" that is the for loop in the console. `54` is the return value of the last `setTimeout` and `undefined` i the return value of the anonymous function.

Comment: @xralf in the first example it's 10, ... 10 because the `setTimeout` function prints the current value of `i` after 10 milliseconds. the current value of i is `10` when those functions execute.

Comment: @Raynos This could be a bug in the future when the for loop should execute 10 times but it executes 11 times, it's good to know this pitfall.

Comment: @xralf no. This is a side effect of testing in the console. Test it in jsfiddle and note the loop only runs 10 times